# Fix slow and weird diagonal movement on slopes in Godot 3D?

Tags: movement, godot, character

I am creating a 3rd-person player controller using move_and_slide_with_snap in the style of WoW, so the player's speed should be the same horizontally no matter what the slope of the terrain they're moving across is. When the player moves across a slope, the speed is slower. Furthermore, if  moving across a slope rather than directly into it, they're not going directly forward but falling slightly as they move.

For example: I'm standing at the bottom-right corner of a ramp, facing slightly to the right of the top-left corner of the ramp. When I move forward, I expect to end up slightly to the right of the top-left corner of the ramp.

[image]

However, when I move forward to the top, I end up on the left side of the top-left corner, rather than on the right side.

[image]

So rather than moving straight, I'm moving slightly down the ramp as I move up it.

[image]

And again, my player speed is slightly lower than when I'm on a flat plane as well. I understand why both of these things happen -- as I'm moving into the ramp, it's pushing back in the direction of its normal. I just don't know conceptually how to fix it. To be clear, my character doesn't slide down when standing still, so that's not the issue.

Code-wise, I'm basically doing this:

```
var movement_direction = Vector3.ZERO
if Input.is_action_pressed("character_move_forward"):
        move_direction -= transform.basis.z
    if Input.is_action_pressed("character_move_backward"):
        move_direction += transform.basis.z
    if Input.is_action_pressed("character_move_left"):
        move_direction -= transform.basis.x
    if Input.is_action_pressed("character_move_right"):
        move_direction += transform.basis.x

velocity = move_direction * movement_speed
velocity = move_and_slide_with_snap(velocity, Vector3.DOWN, Vector3.UP, true)
```

Comment: I've been unable to make a fully reliable solution, which is why I'm not posting an answer. I ran into some bugs when trying to do it. At least for this Godot Physics seems to works better than Bullet. Anyway, the idea would be not slide up any ramp, instead you want to stop when you reach a ramp. Then you will have a movement plane (you can do cross product between UP and the move direction) and the ramp plane (get its normal), the intersection of the planes is a line which direction is the cross of the normals of the planes… Move along that direction (e.g. project move direction on it).